# Ionic Stacked input - Show label below text field

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using the below code to show a stacked in Ionic version 2.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Joy to the world</ion-label>
    <ion-input value="C         G"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

By default the label displayed above the text field.
But I want to show the label below the text field.

**Is it possible to show the label below the text field.**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about overwriting these sass variables:

```
.item-label-stacked .input-wrapper,
.input-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
.label-md[stacked] {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: But there is a big gap between the label and the input text. Is it possible to reduce the gap between the input field and the label. Thank You.