# show text above and below ion-input inside ion-item

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Objective:**
Show text above and below `ion-input` inside `ion-item` like below

[image: text above and below ion-input]

To add **only** the above label, add `stacked` to `ion-label`
To add **only** the below label, add style `flex-direction: column-reverse` to `input-wrapper` as stated in [Ionic Stacked input - Show label below text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506766/ionic-stacked-input-show-label-below-text-field)

**Difficulties:**
There's one `input-wrapper` => cannot alter it to handle both case
Or I haven't find the solution

**Workaround:**
open new `ion-item` to show text below `ion-input`
But then need special handle in css to ignore font, margin...

**Playground:**
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wf6mro?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)
Please concern only home page
"input prefix..." is intended to be under input as remark

Is there any way to add text above and below `ion-input` easily?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please put your code and added your code using  https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @core114 just added